# Can't target staging slot Octopus

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, octopus-deploy

I have set up a deployment in Octopus with the intention of blue/green deployments. I have tried two different approaches but neither of them seem to be taking any notice of the slot I have set up for it.

The two approaches are:

- deploy to staging
- swap slots

or

- deploy to staging
- deploy to production

for both of these I have the Deployment Slot set:

[image]

but neither deploy seems to take any notice of it. If I change the name to anything else i.e. -stagingslot the deployments fail. The logs I get appear to show that the deploymnet has been sucessful:

> 10:16:37   Info     |       Name                      : DevemoTestSlots/stagingslot
> 10:16:37   Info     |       Location                  : West Europe
> 10:16:37   Info     |       Type                      : Microsoft.Web/sites/slots
> 10:16:37   Info     |       Tags                      :
> 10:16:37   Info     |       Virtual Directory Config at end of Deployment:
> 10:16:37   Info     |       VirtualPath        : /
> 10:16:37   Info     |       PhysicalPath       : site\wwwroot
> 10:16:37   Info     |       PreloadEnabled     : True
> 10:16:37   Info     |       VirtualDirectories :
> 10:16:37   Info     |       Releasing Mutex : DevemoTestSlotsstagingslot
> 10:16:37   Verbose  |       Successfully finished Deploy Staging Slot on the Octopus Server

The only issue I can think of at this point is that the DevemoTestSlotsstagingslot shows up as devemotestslots-stagingslot in the dashboard. As I said any alteration in the deployment causes a failure.

Any help targeting the slot will be appreciated.

Comment: It appears that no matter what is done in the script the publish profile that ends up being used ignores slots. More investigation.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the deployment process? Is this using a custom script, a custom step template, or built-in steps with deployment targets?

Comment: CreateAzureWebJob, DeployAzureWebJob, Manual intervention, SwapSlots (built in script). I have variables set up for Azure access and the deploy basically works. Now we want to use slots I have cloned that and attempted to alter it for slots. The first attempt was to complete the DEPLOYMENT_SLOT variable. The problem I have currently is that no matter what I alter in the underlying scripts the profile from the production slot is used to deploy so never deploys to the Staging slot we are attempting to target. Also I am doing this on Octopus v4.0.7 but the Server we wil use for prod is 2018.8.5

Comment: I have started again and using a different template for the deploy which is working but I am deploying two extra directories <ProjectName>/GeneratedWebPackages/ before the app_data directory.

Comment: Deploying to an Azure Web App slot is supported on the Deploy an Azure Web App built-in step. In 2018.8 the slot support works differently, you can create a deployment target for the web app without specifying the slot and then provide the target slot on the step.

Comment: Got it working now \0/ I started a new deploy  and added new tasks for each step I wanted: delete/create staging slot, deploy staging slot, manual intervention, swap slots. I think some of the custom powershell behind the tasks that was set up was causing an issue for me. Following the various tuts got me to the end. Now onto setting configuration how we want it.